# Problem in if else statement inside for loop in python

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

> I seem to have a little problem here in this loop if else.
> Here my if statement doesn't works. My all rows gets red in colour idk probably my first condition gets corrects all time.
> Also when i put else's statement first my rows gets  blue in colour.

```
from tkinter import *
def columns(clmn):
    for i in range(9):
        if i == 3 or 4 or 5:
            Spinbox(from_=1, to=9, bg='red').grid(row=i, column=clmn)
        else:
            Spinbox(from_=1, to=9, bg='green').grid(row=i, column=clmnSpinbox(from_=1, to=9, bg='blue').grid(row=i, column=clmn)

for i in range(9):
    columns(i)
```

Comment: Please avoid that mistake I have done in else statement block code(Spinbox...) My bad

Comment: "My all rows gets red in colour idk probably my first condition gets corrects all time." It's good that you had the idea. The next step in [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code is to *test* that hypothesis. For example: try the code in isolation, by just making a function with that `if` block. Try different values of `i` and see whether the block is entered. Try considering the *condition* by itself: for example, if you try `0 == 3 or 4 or 5` at the interpreter prompt, what does it give back?